# Is there a method for detecting if an IP address should be skipped as source on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-server-2003, netsh

If an adapter has several IP addresses defined, you can get an overview of which IP addresses should be skipped as source. This is done by executing the following command:

```
netsh int ipv4 show ipaddresses level=verbose
```

On Windows 2003 Server this feature doesn't exist, but it's still possible to define more than one IP address for an adapter.

My question is:

Is there a way of detecting whether or not an IP address from an adapter can be used as a source IP? I don't care if it's a hack. I just need to be able to determine which IP addresses for a given adapter can be used as source.

On Windows 7, it's done like this (see example):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Does Windows 2003 actually allow you to define an IP address that can't be used as a source address?  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: you can add as many as you want but they might not "work"

Comment: How exactly do you tell Windows 2003 that an IP address you're adding is not to be used as a source address?

Comment: you can't ...that's part of the problem. is the question not clear?

Comment: I don't understand.  You are asking how to distinguish normal IP addresses from skip-as-source IP addresses.  But if there are no skip-as-source IP addresses in Windows 2003, then the problem is trivial: *all* IP addresses configured for an adapter are normal, *none* of them are skip-as-source.  That is, you can use any of the IP addresses assigned to the adapter as a source address.

Comment: my question isn't clear i guess. all IP addresses are normal (as you put it) but all of them might not be reachable by a remote IP endpoint on a (W)LAN. try adding 192.168.0.7 and 10.0.0.5 to your adapter and see if you can reach the last address via a 192.168.0.1 gateway from another computer. the program on .0.7 must figure out which IP to use as a source IP when sending network packets out . does that make it clearer?

Comment: In the simplest case, where there is an internal subnet and an external subnet sharing the same adapter, I think you could do this by looking up the gateway address(es) for the adapter; given an IP address and subnet mask you can determine the associated subnet, and if there is a gateway address in that subnet, the IP address should be suitable.  In the general case you might need to either test the addresses by connecting to a selection of known-good internet servers, or allow the system admin to configure your software with the correct address.

Comment: (I think the assumption built into the operating system is that the system administrator isn't supposed to do that in the first place.  So it isn't unreasonable for your software to ask for assistance in coping with this scenario.)